# Check if registry key is present before Get-ItemProperty

Tags: powershell, if-statement, directory

I've been trying to create a script that checks which applications are installed on a remote server. So far I've been able to get it working to do the job when everything is in place.
However, one of my servers are a bit broken and the "uninstall" registry key is missing from the registry.

So before doing `Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"` and `Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"` I want to check if the registry key is present and if that isn't the case, I wish to run `Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from win32_product"`

Currently when I run it on the machine that is missing the "Uninstall" registry key I get

```
Cannot find path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...rsion\Uninstall:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ServerName001
```

Current script:

```
# Change to computer you wish to search.
$ComputerName = "ServerName001"
$ScriptPath = Get-Location

$GetWmiObject_Win32Product = $ScriptPath.ToString() + $ComputerName + "_Get-WmiObject-win32_Product.csv"
$GetItemProperty = $ScriptPath.ToString() + $ComputerName + "_Get-ItemProperty.csv"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    $directoryInfo64bit = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Measure-Object
    $directoryInfo32bit = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Measure-Object

    $Apps = @()
    if($directoryInfo64bit.count -eq 0){
        Write-Output "No 64bit Uninstall folder"
    }else{
        $Apps += Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
    }
    if($directoryInfo32bit.count -eq 0){
        Write-Output "No 32bit Uninstall folder"
    }else{
        $Apps += Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
    }

    $Apps | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Publisher, DisplayVersion, InstallDate, InstallLocation, PSComputerName
} | Export-Csv -Path $GetItemProperty -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8

Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from win32_product" -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object -Property Name, Vendor, Version, PSComputerName | Export-Csv -Path $GetWmiObject_Win32Product -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: Why use the `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet at all when you can get all info from the registry? Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65215516/9898643) for instance

Comment: Another thought: If you only get the error for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\...`, then the machine might run a 32-bit Windows version, in which case `Wow6432Node` doesn't exist. There is nothing broken in this case, so you can simply exclude this case using `Test-Path` and continue to use `Get-ItemProperty` for the "normal" registry key.

Comment: You can always use get-package to check for software installs.

Comment: As a side note: [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is exponentially expensive.

Comment: @Theo want to use Get-WmiObject in the cases where the registry is FUBAR and uninstall information is missing. I.e. in my case the machine displays completely blanked if I go to programs and features to try and uninstall something.

Comment: Netbeans puts in an invalid registry key that gives an exception in get-itemproperty.