# how to get all installed software in windows machine using 'Get-ItemProperty' from powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command

I tried this in my script.
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* | Select-Object DisplayName | Format-Table -AutoSize >>as.txt

Output:
'Get-ItemProperty' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Installed software using registry keys in PowerShell, some software name not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213998/getting-installed-software-using-registry-keys-in-powershell-some-software-name)

Comment: You need to start a PowerShell console to be able to run PowerShell cmdlets. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an x64 version of Windows, perhaps something like this single line batch file would help:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "$MyProgs = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'; $MyProgs += Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'; $MyProgs.DisplayName | Sort-Object -Unique" 1>"as.txt"
```